# R: Combining Two Contour Plots Together

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. I made the two following plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

data_1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,10,10), b = rnorm(100,10,10), c = as.factor("one"))


data_2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,10,10), b = rnorm(100,10,10), c = as.factor("two"))


p1 = ggplot(data_1, aes(x = a, y = 
          b)) +
        geom_density_2d_filled() + 
        ggtitle("Plot 1")

p2 = ggplot(data_2, aes(x = a, y = 
          b)) +
        geom_density_2d_filled() + 
        ggtitle("Plot 2")

plot_grid(p1, p2)
```

[image]

**My Question:** Is there a way to combine both of these plots in a single plot, such that it doesn't look "too messy"?

I tried the following code:

```
ggplot(final, aes(x = a, y = 
                      b, colour = c)) +
    geom_density_2d_filled() + 
    ggtitle("Combined")
```

[image]

But this is very difficult to read.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean combining the legend only or the distributions as well?

Comment: @ Mael : Thank you for your reply! Can the legends be combined? I am not sure how to do this - I am looking for a way such that someone would know that these are two different plots of two different species (e.g. height/weight of elephants vs tigers)

Comment: data_2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,10,10), b = rnorm(100,10,10), c = as.factor("two")) this can be changed to data_2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,100,10), b = rnorm(100,100,10), c = as.factor("two")) so it looks more obvious

Comment: I guess you have several options to make it more readable.  You can remove the legend (`show.legend = F`) in the `geom_density_2d_filled` function if it not super important. Combining both plots might not be a good option because they are pretty much in the same place so they overlap

Comment: What exactly does "too messy" mean? How are you measuring "difficulty to read"? If you want general data visualization advice, that's more on-topic for [stats.se]. This doesn't seem to be a specific, non-opinion based programming question at the moment.

Comment: You can look [here](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/shared_legends.html) if you want to combine the legend with cowplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean sth. like this? Here, a contour plot is used to overlap multiple 2d kernel densities:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

set.seed(1337)
data_1 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,10,10), b = rnorm(100,10,10), c = as.factor("one"))
data_2 = data.frame(a = rnorm(100,10,10), b = rnorm(100,10,10), c = as.factor("two"))

bind_rows(
  data_1,
  data_2
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(a, b, color = c)) +
    geom_density2d()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>